# NSTextView CoreText note: Client requested name

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appkit, nstextview

On a `NSTextView` when setting the font to `.monospacedSystemFont` Xcode shows warnings regarding an invalid font. Example:

```
CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNSMono-Bold", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the same font for the `NSTextView.typingAttributes`, example:

```
let textView = NSTextView()
textView.typingAttributes[.font] = NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize, weight: .regular)
textView.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize, weight: .regular)
```